# Why transform:translateY is not working with background-attachment:fixed image

Tags: css

`transform:translateY` is not working with `background-attachment:fixed` image. Can anyone check the CSS placed below.

```
.fixed-bg {
  background-image: url(Life.jpeg);
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: mymove 5s alternate ;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s alternate ;  
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10);
  }
} 
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10);
  }
}
```

Can someone help me with this pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made an mistake on keyframes. The following code is working - the `div` moves down. On the `body` element the code doesn't work!

As an alternative you can use [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) too. There is a animation named `slideOutDown`.

```css
.fixed-bg {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: mymove 5s alternate ;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s alternate ;  
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(10px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  }
} 
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(10px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bg"></div>
```